# How can I create a column of running values?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I have been creating reports to get use to the tools available etc.
I have come across an issue where I cannot get a column of running values to appear correctly.

I have circled the column where I want the running values to be displayed based on the values in "Min Heads" column.

[image]
I have tried this expression:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!DefaultValue.Value, Sum, "Tablix")
```

Where Tablix is the Matrix, this calculated the running values for each row. I have tried changing the scope to the row's group and dataset but haven't had any luck.

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong and could tell me how to create the expression for the results I require.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the scope of the function to the name of the Min Heads column. So it would be something like this:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!DefaultValue.Value, Sum, "Min_Heads")
```

I think that the scopes you have tried are too wide, or simply not valid for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it did not work.


I got the error message:
The Value expression for the text box ‘AccHeads’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for RunningValue, RowNumber or Previous.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to the name of a containing group within the Tablix ‘Tablix’.
----------------------------
The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
----------------------------
An error occurred during local report processing.

Comment: Have you tried MinHeads as the scope? That is what I have in my answer.

Comment: Yes I tried: =RunningValue(Fields!DefaultValue.Value, Sum, Min_Heads")  Where Min_Heads is the column name.

Comment: Same error, or do you get nothing at all with the Min Heads scope? Or, do you not get the expected value?

Comment: When you select the cell that shows "Min Heads" in the screen shot of this question, what name does VS (or BIDS) show in the properties pane? That is what you need to use for the scope. I feel like the name might be the issue.

Comment: Min_Heads, I have tried typing and copying and pasting the name in to ensure it wan't a typo.

Comment: The value it displays is a number, yes? It's not being returned from the database as a string for some reason?

Comment: it is a number, when i used the tablex as the scope it calculated the running values for a row so it must an int

Comment: I am going to need a screenshot of the report in design mode, including the Row Groups and Column Groups. Without that I am just guessing. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114367/discussion-between-rav-and-r-richards).